# In Swift (5), how to I pass an "Any..." parameter to a print() statement without it printing as an array?

Tags: swift, debug-print

I have a global enum I use for global functions that I only want to run when the app is in debug. It looks something like this:

```
public enum Debug {
    static func print(_ items: Any..., separator: String = " ", terminator: String = "\n") {
        #if DEBUG
        Swift.print(items, separator: separator, terminator: terminator)
        #endif
    }
}
```

However, when I use

`Debug.print(35)`

the output is

`["35"]`

What I want is for the output to look just like a regular print statement:

`35`

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong or could do different?

It kind of looks like I have to "unpack" the `items` parameter and put each one in the print statement individually, but that seems like the wrong approach.

```
public enum Debug {
    static func print(_ items: Any..., separator: String = " ", terminator: String = "\n") {
        #if DEBUG
        for item in items {
            Swift.print(item, terminator: separator)
        }
        Swift.print("", terminator: terminator)
        #endif
    }
}
```

This works...but makes me cringe. There's got to be a better solution...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply map your items into strings, join them with the separator and print the resulting string:

```
public enum Debug {
    static func print(_ items: Any..., separator: String = " ", terminator: String = "\n") {
        #if DEBUG
        Swift.print(items.map({String(describing: $0)}).joined(separator: separator), terminator: terminator)
        #endif
    }
}
```

Or simply:

Comment: That's a good answer. I was hoping to avoid a loop - see my updated question

Comment: I might be wrong but I don't think you have an alternative

Comment: If in 24 hrs nobody has an alternative, I'll mark this as the answer. I think you're right, I just don't want you to be, haha.

Comment: Smart! My guess is the map function is faster than a for loop, so I'll accept this as a reasonable compromise

Comment: It is not about speed. It is about achieving the same result as if you were actually printing them

Comment: Really? I thought that the for loop was slower than other iterating functions because of what happens in the back end, so I was trying to avoid having it run every time I print something out.
Either way, this is basically what I was looking to do, so I'll keep the accepted status.

Comment: My intent was to replicate the behavior you would expect when using the original print function

Comment: I see what you mean now. Well, it works! So thank you!

Comment: From what I understand, it just gives --more-- information. It doesn't do an `#if DEBUG` check. Also, I want the option to print to a log file instead when this goes out to production so I have something to reference when errors occur on devices out of the office.